# createmetadata/Updatemetadata/Upsertmetadata does not work for flowactions

Tags: workflow, metadata-api, c#

I'm able to create new workflow rules but unable to create workflow flow actions (which are intended) to act as triggers to invoke flows via the Metadata API - Create/Update/Upsert calls. I don't get any errors back. I validated the xml using the Force.com IDE and the flow action was getting created without any issues via the IDE (Save).  I also don't get any errors back. Do you know if there are any prerequisites for create/update/upsert using metadata api? I use C#.

Any pointers will help.

Thanks,
VB